# Solve $\sqrt[n]{z^n}=z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

For what values ​​of $z$.$\sqrt[n]{z^n}=z$, with principal root.

**Try:**

I do a particular case when $n=2$.

I claim that $z=0$ or $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ where $0\le \theta<\pi$. So i suppose that $z\ne 0$ and $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ where $\pi\le\theta<2\pi$ and I'm going to reach a contradiction. Then, $z^2=|z|^2e^{i2\theta}=|z|^2e^{i(2\theta-2\pi)}$ and since $0\leq 2\theta-2\pi<2\pi$ we have that, $$\sqrt{z^2}=|z|e^{i(2\theta-2\pi)/2}=|z|e^{i\theta}e^{-i\pi}=-z\neq z$$
Therefore, $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ where $0\le \theta<\pi$ as desire.

But I don't know how to extend it for the general case, I think the $\theta$ would be between $0$ and $n\pi$. Some help.

Comment: Isn't this false even for $n=2$? $\sqrt {(-i)^{2}}\neq -i$

Comment: I worded the question wrong. @geetha290krm